# Exporting NULL Values from Hive to Teradata

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata, sqoop

I have a table in Hive where certain columns have NULL values and I'm using Teradata connector to export the table from Hadoop to Teradata. My issue is that NULL values are taken as string NULL instead of NULL. How to export NULL values directly to Teradata? Please help.

Comment: How are your tables defined in Hive?  In particular, is something specified for "serialization.null.format"?

Comment: no serialization.null.format is used. Its a simple table inserting values from an existing CTAS. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a token value appropriate for the data type that isn't present in the domain of the column combined with COALESCE()? It's a workaround, if you are not able to get standard sqoop parameters to work with the Teradata Connector for Hadoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to export NULL values by making use of -null string parameter(optional) in teradata hadoop connector. As suggest in the comments section by Rob.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the  `input-null-string` parameter in the export command? According to the [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax_3):

> The --input-null-string and --input-null-non-string arguments are optional. If --input-null-string is not specified, then the string "null" will be interpreted as null for string-type columns. If --input-null-non-string is not specified, then both the string "null" and the empty string will be interpreted as null for non-string columns. Note that, the empty string will be always interpreted as null for non-string columns, in addition to other string if specified by --input-null-non-string.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jaime! I'm using Teradata Hadoop connector not stoop. Not sure if this parameter is applicable to TD connector. Is it?

Comment: Sorry then, I don't know if that's possible. I thought you were using Sqoop because you tagged the question as such.

Comment: I think the Teradata Connector for Hadoop is using sqoop and provides an additional set of parameters on top of those that sqoop normally supports. The documentation for Teradata Connector (or Cloudera's Connector) are vague on what additional parameters are supported. Might be worth trying the suggestion here.